# SIGILL Stack overflow

Tags: gcc

From https://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/617807

If I don't call abort on line 44, my program crashes with SIGILL.

Why doesn't it exit cleanly? I put the value of the frame pointer back where it was but the stack is still corrupt. I suspect there is an extra frame on the stack from calling into `i_never_called_this_code` that I didn't account for.

This is a personal exercise so I can learn about the stack.

Note: Run the code at your own risk.

Bugsquasher

**EDIT**
As per the comment, here is the code.

```
#warning RUN @ YOUR OWN RISK NEWBIE 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
typedef void (*VOIDFUNC)(); 
typedef VOIDFUNC* VOIDFUNCPTR; 
static VOIDFUNC old_data = (VOIDFUNC)0; 
static VOIDFUNCPTR return_address = (VOIDFUNCPTR)0; 
static VOIDFUNCPTR stack_address = (VOIDFUNCPTR)0; 
void put_it_back() { 
   if (return_address) { 
      /// Put back the previous value 
      fprintf(stderr , "Returning data {%p} to %p\n" , old_data , return_address); 
      *return_address = old_data; 
   } 
} 
void i_never_called_this_code() { 
   fprintf(stderr , "\n\nArbitrary code execution... oops!\n\n"); 
   /// Attempt to repair the damage, so it goes back to the 'CORRECT' frame 
   put_it_back(); 
   stack_address = return_address; 
   fprintf(stderr , "***Stack Address is %p ***\n" , stack_address); 
   /// We better abort before shit gets crazy 
   //   abort();
   /// haha just kidding 
   /// No really 
   //   abort();
   /// you really want to know what happens, don't you? 
   /// Ahem abort(); 
} 
void break_the_stack(char* stackptr) { 
   /// Store the old data (ie, return address we're SUPPOSED to be going to 
   old_data = *(VOIDFUNCPTR)(stackptr); 
   return_address = (VOIDFUNCPTR)stackptr; 
   fprintf(stderr , "Reading data {%p} at %p\n" , old_data , return_address); 
   /// Smash the stackptr, 
   /// When we find the return address stored on the stack, we replace it with our function address 
   /// that's where it will go next 
   /// Basicallly, we're calling our code without calling it 
   /// Once that's done, 411 UR B4535 B310NG 2 US 
   *(VOIDFUNCPTR)(stackptr) = i_never_called_this_code; 
} 
int main(int argc , char** argv) { 
   char* stack = (char*)&stack; 
   (void)argc; 
   (void)argv; 
   while (1) { 
      stack -= sizeof(unsigned int); 
      fprintf(stdout , "0x%lx\n" , (unsigned long int)stack); 
      break_the_stack(stack); 
      put_it_back(); 
      if (stack_address) {/// == (VOIDFUNCPTR)stack) 
         break; 
      } else { 
         /// Cleanliness is next to godliness 
         ///         *return_address = old_data; 
      } 
   } 
   fprintf(stderr , "What just happened?\n"); 
   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You should copy your code into the question instead of linking to it

Comment: @CacahueteFrito there ya go